# Wave equation for a contracting circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the wave equation for a periodically contracting and expanding circle, in two dimensions. It was so long ago that I did any kind of similar calculation that I have kinda forgotten how to proceed. What I remember is that the wave equation in polar coordinates leads to the Bessel equation. But is that really the way to go about it in this case?

Edit: The reason for my confusion stems from the fact that:

$$\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}=0$$
where $\alpha=(\tau,\lambda)$ and $X(\tau,\lambda)=(X^1,X^2)$, so for polar coordinates I would have that $r(\tau,\lambda)$ similarly for $\theta$. Therefore I doubt that I would need reparametrize the differential equation to Bassel equation. Am I correct in thinking that it would be unwise to do so?